# Why is child element inheriting parent opacity?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, opacity

Simple question (I hope) that's eluding me.. I have an overlay for a modal window that sets the opacity to .87, however my div inside that (the modal content) seems to inherit that opacity.

CSS:

```
body { background-color:black; }
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:.87;
}

#overlay > div {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:15px;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:1;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div>some stuff here</div>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ57q/) (the background should be pure white, not mixed). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't know that child elements inherited that of the parent

Comment: Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ57q/2/)

Comment: @Vucko that *almost* works. This is only a snippet of my entire thing (enough to reproduce), but the modal is not opaque, but the overlay isn't either now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opacity is inherited by child elements AFAIK.
Why not try using:

```
background:rgba(0,0,0,.87);
```

I removed the black background.
Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zZ57q/3/

Comment: Change opacity into that.